# Ruby on Rails Controller methods separately?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, methods, controller

Just to be educated I wanted to know if it is a good practice to have one controller method for both GET and POST actions, e.g `def signup ... end`, which would display a form and if `request.post?` is true - then perform all the business-logic and so on. Is it any good approach, or should I have these methods being separated from each other ?

Thanks in advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is little difference in code organisation either way.

With separate methods, it looks like:

```
def signup_create
  # create here
end
def signup_new
  # render here
end
```

With the same method, it looks like:

```
def signup
  if request.post?
    # create here
  else
    # render here
  end
end
```

It looks like they are both reasonably well organised. Choose what your prefer. If they are the default CRUD methods, separate methods are nice, given that there are separate names thought up already (eg. `new` vs `create`, `edit` vs `update`).

If they are not CRUD, or extra forms on the page, and you can only think of one name for it  (like `signup`), feel free to overload the name and use the same method.

Comment: Thanks! Now I feel much more confident in my approach :)

Answer (score 3):

I think it'll be much better to define a separate action for the post request. You can obviously get it done within the same action, but if you're going to write a big if..else block in sign_up action you may as well use another action. You could call it create if you're short of names :P . It makes the code more logical and readable.

Comment: +1, I would follow REST too. Plus, a method should do *one* thing.

Comment: OK. I'll stick with that! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

i think that separate actions for different requests are better if u are using(or going to use) method based authorization (eg cancan).